# Concatenate String and structure member to form the another structure

Tags: c, macros, concatenation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define num_Harmonics 4

typedef struct

{
    char *ID;
    float fre;
}SpeedFrequency_t;

typedef struct
{
    float amp;
    float ph;
}SpeedAmpPhase_t;

#define str_cat(A,B) A ## B

int main()

{
    SpeedFrequency_t SpeedFreq[num_Harmonics];
    SpeedAmpPhase_t  SpeedAmpPhs1X;
    SpeedAmpPhase_t  SpeedAmpPhs2X;
    SpeedAmpPhase_t  SpeedAmpPhs3X;
    SpeedAmpPhase_t  SpeedAmpPhs4X;
    
    SpeedFreq[0].ID = "1X";
    SpeedFreq[0].fre = 30;
    
    SpeedFreq[1].ID = "2X";
    SpeedFreq[1].fre = 60;
    
    SpeedFreq[2].ID = "3X";
    SpeedFreq[2].fre = 90;
    
    SpeedFreq[3].ID = "4X";
    SpeedFreq[3].fre = 160;
    // concatenate the SpeedAmpPhs and SpeedFreq[0].ID to form the 
    // another structure SpeedAmpPhs1X and assign the appropriate
    // Value
    str_cat(SpeedAmpPhs,SpeedFreq[0].ID).amp = SpeedFreq[0].fre; 
    str_cat(SpeedAmpPhs,SpeedFreq[0].ID).ph  = SpeedFreq[0].fre * 15;
    return 0;
}
```

In the program above, I have 2 structure, first structure has a pointer to a char and other member is a `float`. The second structure has 2 float variables.
From the first structure, I have declared an array of 4. The float values are used in the algorithms to compute the 2 values and these values are used to fill the second structures (I can't share the algorithm).

The pointer to char consists of a string, information which is essential to assign value to the second structure. To assign appropriate value to the second struct I have used the string information (from the first struct).
Eg: "1x" is the string in the first structure, so I have to concatenate first struct string to form the 2 struct declaration variable "SpeedAmpPhs1X" and using these values fill the value to 2 second structure. Which resulted in the error.
SO I need experts' help to resolve it.

I'm getting this error after concatenating using Macro.

```
error: 'SpeedAmpPhsSpeedFreq' undeclared (first use in this function); 
did you mean 'SpeedAmpPhs1X'? str_cat(SpeedAmpPhs,SpeedFreq[0].ID).amp = SpeedFreq[0].fre;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please [edit] your question and a) tag the relevant language, b) add all of the information into the question itself, c) clarify exactly what you're trying to do with a clear example.

Comment: You can only use the token pasting operator `##` to concatenate tokens at compile time.  It is not a general string concatenation method, and doesn't do anything at runtime.  You try to use `str_cat(SpeedAmpPhs,SpeedFreq[0].ID)` which yields `SpeedAmpPhsSpeedFreq[0].ID` which isn't a known variable.  You need to write 'proper' string manipulation code, handling memory allocation and using functions from `<string.h>`, etc.